# IIS7 ISAPI Not loading php.ini

Tags: php, iis-7, isapi

After installing php as ISAPI on IIS7 phpinfo function shows that no php.ini were loaded:

Loaded Configuration File   (none)

By command line PHP is loading php.ini file successfully

```
C:\PHP>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\PHP\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

How can I solve it?

The only php.ini file on the server is on C:\PHP. There is no php.ini on C:\Windows.

The php.ini file were created by php installer and is untouched so far.

tks

Comment: phpinfo available here: http://189.16.80.210/phpinfo.php

Comment: On FastCGI PHP.INI was successfully loaded